# Inno Setup: Delete Run registry key on uninstall

Tags: registry, inno-setup, uninstallation

I need my application to start on boot and I realize this by creating a value at HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Run. However, I'd like to remove that value upon uninstallation of the application. How?

I use Inno Setup to setup my application. So far, I came up with two approaches: Either to delete the value directly from setup or to run the application during uninstallation and tell it to remove the value. Both approaches however fail, because the setup application needs to run under a different user, which makes the HKCU registry root point somewhere else.

Comment: So, you are running your setup with admin rights ? If so, you are writing into the admin's space since `HKCU` maps to the current user which might be impersonated admin. For per user installations you should run your setup as the target user, not as someone else (`PrivilegesRequired=lowest`).

Comment: In that case, the user wouldn't be able to install the application into the Program Files directory, would he?

Comment: No. But per user installations are not even supposed to write there. Program Files is common for all users. Consider what happens if you install one version of your app (into the Program Files folder) and write a run key (with some command line params that your app. understand) into the originally logged on user's registry space. Then a different user log on and install a different version of your app, overwrite it in the common Program Files folder and for his own registry space write a different run key (with different command line). Now what will you do with the first user's run key ?

Comment: Will the new application stored in the Program Files folder know how to run with the first user's run key ? Sure, that's just an example. But even that may happen. Take Program Files as a folder for per machine installations. Quite good reading about this topic [`is here`](http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=Vista_considerations#Types_of_Installer).

Comment: Okay, I see it's going to be most reasonable to write the value into HKLM. :) Thank you for sharing your point of view.